# $q$-multinomial series

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics

I have the following code, which produces a [$q$-multinomial coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-MultinomialCoefficient.html), but selected randomly according to a Poisson distribution.

Consider a 3D lattice path selected uniformly at random from a cuboidal domain with random dimensions $m1,m2,m3$, then average over all dimensions, where each value has mean $l1,l2,l3$, respectively:

```
qmultinomial[q_, m1_, m2_, m3_] := 
 Normal@Series[QFactorial[m1 + m2 + m3, q]/(
   QFactorial[m1, q] QFactorial[m2, q] QFactorial[m3, q]), {q, 0, 
    m1 m2 + m2 m3}]
l1 = 3;
l2 = 3;
l3 = 3;
maxi = 10;
maxj = 10;
maxk = 10;
poissonqmult = 
   N@Series[
     Total@Flatten@
       Table[1/Multinomial[i, j, k] (Exp[-l1] l1^i)/i! (
         Exp[-l2] l1^j)/j! (Exp[-l3] l1^k)/
         k! qmultinomial[q, i, j, k], {i, 0, maxi}, {j, 0, maxj}, {k, 
         0, maxk}], {q, 0, 64}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPlot@Transpose[{Table[
    i, {i, 1, Length@CoefficientList[poissonqmult, q]}], 
   CoefficientList[poissonqmult, q]}]
```

which gives

```
{32.9553, Null}
```

[image]

The problem is the code is slow, and I need to increase $maxi,maxj,maxk$ to finite values which are quite large (technically infinite). Is there some way I can speed it up? Perhaps using `ParallelTable`?

Comment: One small note: your last line can be replaced by `ListPlot@CoefficientList[poissonqmult, q]`. `ListPlot` will automatically assume (1,2,3...) abscissae if none are provided. Unfortunately it won't make your code faster, but it certainly is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the series expansion altogether and define the `qmultinomial` directly:

```
ClearAll[qmultinomial]
qmultinomial[q_, m1_, m2_, m3_] := 
 QFactorial[m1 + m2 + m3, q]/(QFactorial[m1, q] QFactorial[m2, q] QFactorial[m3, q])
```

Then retain the rest of the code as written and you will obtain ostensibly the same result, but in 1.5 s (your original code took ca. vs. 20 s on my machine):

```
l1 = 3;
l2 = 3;
l3 = 3;
maxi = 10;
maxj = 10;
maxk = 10;
poissonqmult = 
   N@Series[
     Total@Flatten@
       Table[1/Multinomial[i, j, k] (Exp[-l1] l1^i)/
          i! (Exp[-l2] l1^j)/j! (Exp[-l3] l1^k)/k! qmultinomial[q, i, 
          j, k], {i, 0, maxi}, {j, 0, maxj}, {k, 0, maxk}], {q, 0, 
      64}]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListPlot@CoefficientList[poissonqmult, q]

(* Out: {1.58515, Null} *)
```

[image: plot obtained]

Comment: Ok nice, just remove the initial series. Thank you. Big help.